# How to fix Unknown type name error with typedef struct?

Tags: c++

Here's my code in a header file:

```
typedef struct _aaa
{
    static void do_something(t_bbb *b); //this line is problematic
} t_aaa;

typedef struct _bbb
{
    t_aaa *a;
} t_bbb;
```

But it says:

> Unknown type name `t_bbb`

How can I make the code compilable?

Comment: Why do you all hate my question?

Comment: I did not downvote, but I suspect it's because the answer is very easy to find if you google the error message. It shows no research from your side.

Comment: I didn't vote, but that's a kind of problem that should be addressed in any beginners' book, so well, one "quality measure" for question is the amount of research you put yourself into the question -- see?

Comment: Plus, why do you tag with C? This is not C.

Comment: I recommend to change your practice of using identifiers starting with "_".

Comment: if it is c++, why we need a typedef?

Comment: @Klaus indeed unnecessary, but a forward declaration would be needed anyways.

Comment: @Yunnosch which is a very strong recommendation .. this kind of identifiers is actually reserved for the implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a forward declaration:

```
struct _bbb;
typedef struct _bbb t_bbb;

typedef struct _aaa
{
```

Comment: No need to declare the `struct _bbb` separately, the `typedef` will suffice as forward declaration.

Comment: Since this is c++, you may want to remove the `typedef`.